# Where can I find the Tomcat log written out by 'grails run-app'?

Tags: grails

While running grails app in 'dev' mode using 'grails run-app', where is the default Tomcat log file located written out by the embedded Tomcat come with Grails (1.2.2) installation?

Answer (score 6):

There isn't a default log file, the output to the log gets written to stdout.

Comment: Some output goes to the stdout, but not Tomcat access log.

Comment: Just to note on the latest version of grails (2.2.3) there is no log appender configured, so initially no logs get written at all. To change this you just need to edit conf/Config.groovy and uncomment the appenders{ console ...} lines. This will send log messages (with level Error and above) to the console (stdout)

Answer (score 0):

Should be `$CATALINA_HOME/logs/catalina.out`

Comment: My other stand-along Tomcat writes log out to $CATALINA_HOME/logs/catalina.out, not the location the embedded Tomcat comes with Grails logs access requests. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Do you have log4j configured in Config.groovy?

Comment: My log4j in Config.groovy is pretty standard in its default value. More pointers to have my Tomcat (embedded) log written out some where that I can see is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define an log4j root logger in your Config.groovy like this:

```
log4j = {
    appenders {
        // console name:'stdout', layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%c{2} %m%n')
        // file name:'file', file:'app.log'
    }

    // By default, messages are logged at the warn level to the console and the app.log
    root {
        warn 'stdout'
        // warn 'stdout','file'
        additivity = true
    }
...
}
```

This example also shows how to configure the logging pattern. Also it shows how to configure file logging. The appenders section is optional and just needed to configure the logging pattern or file logger.